# Hyperlink not redirecting correctly

Tags: hyperref, hyperlink

[image: PDF should look like this, after redirecting where EDM (Target) is in focus]
[image: But currently, it is looking like this. Where EDM is out of focus]

```latex
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{article}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
 \usepackage{titletoc} 
 \usepackage{titlesec} 
 \usepackage{ltxtable}
 \usepackage{filecontents} 
 \usepackage{lscape}
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage{color} 
 \usepackage{tabularx} 


 \usepackage{hyperref} 
\hypersetup{colorlinks, linkcolor=link, filecolor=link, urlcolor=link, citecolor=link, pdfpagemode=UseOutlines, pdfcreator=TrainBraC, pdfauthor={E. Hohmann}, pdfproducer=PDFLaTeX, pdftitle=Schulungsprojekt, pdfsubject=Brake calculation}
\begin{document}
\section*{Table of content}\startcontents\printcontents{l}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}
\clearpage
\phantomsection\section*{List of modifications}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of modifications}
\begin{longtable}{c|c|c|p{7.5cm}}
Revision&Date&File processed by&Notes\hline

01&\hyperref[lb:EDM]{EDM}&E. Hohmann&Some random  text\\
\hline

\end{longtable}




\clearpage
\section{Information of Software Versions}
\subsection{Information of Versions}


\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|}
\caption{Version of brake system DLLs}
\hline
TrainPart&Type&Version&Designation\hline

\endfirsthead
\caption{ContinuationVersion of brake system DLLs}
\hline
TrainPart&Type&Version&Designation\hline

\endhead
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Continued on next page}
\hline
\endfoot
\hline
\multicolumn{4}{c}{}
\endlastfoot
M&Electrodynamic brake&1.0.1&\phantomsection{ED M}\label{lb:EDM}\\
&Tread brake unit&1.0.0&PECM\\
&Tread brake unit&1.0.0&PECMP\\
\hline
N1&Tread brake unit&1.0.0&PECN1\\
&Tread brake unit&1.0.0&PECN1P\\
&Electrodynamic brake&1.0.1&ED N1\\
\hline
T&Disc brake&1.0.0&UPT\\
&Tread brake unit&1.0.0&PECT\\
&Tread brake unit&1.0.0&PECTP\\
\hline
N2&Tread brake unit&1.0.0&PECN2\\
&Tread brake unit&1.0.0&PECN2P\\
&Electrodynamic brake&1.0.1&ED N2\\
\hline

\end{longtable}



\end{document}
```

Comment: the code does not compile

Comment: also hyperref should be loaded last

Comment: I tried to clean up the code display a bit. The ```\makeatletter\\\\``` looks *extremely* suspicious, do you really have that in your code? Note also that you seem to load a lot of packages. Do you need all of them? `hyperref` should generally be loaded last. There are also a few packages (`scrpage2`) that are outdated

Comment: If you like my answer and it was helpful, please consider [upvoting](http://tex.stackexchange.com/privileges/vote-up) (by clicking on the arrows next to the score) and/or marking it as the [accepted answer](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852) (by clicking on the checkmark ✓).

Answer (score 3):

You have a lot of errors in your code and some missunderstanding.

1. Package `scrpage2` is used in KOMA-Script classes like `scrartcl`. It is obsolete. You should use instead `fancyhdr` (for documents not using KOMA-Script) or you need to call package `scrextend` to be able to use then package `scrlayer-scrpage` (the successor of `scrpage2`).
2. Package `caption2` is obsolete, use instead package `caption`!
3. Package `hyperref` should be called in your case last!
4. You use a lot of `setlength` commands. You should better use package `geometry` for this. See the documentation with `texdoc geometry` ...
5. You have some eroors in the usage of captions for `longtable`: Captions in `longtable` needs an `\\` at the end.
6. You can not use `p` only in `longtable`, it must be something like `p{7.5cm}`. Change the value `7.5cm` for your needs!
7. You are using a lot of packages and commands in your code. Do you know from each one what is does? If not, delete/comment them, check the changings in the layout and read the documentations of each package!

The following corrected code compiles without errors (but the layout might differ to that what you want):

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{article}

\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage[OT1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{helvet}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{color}

\usepackage{pdfpages}
%\usepackage[flushleft]{caption2} % <============================== ?????
\usepackage{caption} % <======== caption2 outdated, use caption instead!
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lastpage}
\usepackage{afterpage}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{needspace}
\usepackage{tabularx}

% only used in KOMA-Script with class `scrartcl` or with package `scrextend`
%\usepackage{scrextend}
%\usepackage{scrlayer-scrpage} % <======================================= scrpage2 obsolet
%\pagestyle{scrheadings}
%\setheadsepline{0.25pt}
%\setfootsepline{0.25pt}

\usepackage{hyperref}

% <===================================== Why not using package geometry?
\setlength{\topmargin}{-0.9in}
\setlength{\textwidth}{470pt}
\setlength{\oddsidemargin}{0pt}
\setlength{\textheight}{640pt}
\setlength{\headheight}{70pt}
\setlength{\footskip}{50pt}
\setlength{\evensidemargin}{0pt} \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\setlength{\parskip}{1ex plus 1ex minus 1ex}

 \setcounter{LTchunksize}{20}
 \newlength{\minrowheight}
 \newlength{\tblheightcaption}
 \newlength{\tblcwA}
 \newlength{\tblcwB}
 \newlength{\tmp}

 \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}
 \renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.2}
 \renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.0}
 \renewcommand{\encodingdefault}{T1}
 \renewcommand{\thefigure}{\thesection{}.\arabic{figure}}
 \renewcommand{\thetable}{\thesection{}.\arabic{table}}
 \renewcommand{\captionsize}{\normalsize}
 \renewcommand{\d}{d}
 \renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markboth{\emph{#1}}{}}
 \renewcommand\floatpagefraction{0.8}
 \renewcommand\textfraction{0.2} 
 \renewcommand\topfraction{0.8}
 \renewcommand\bottomfraction{0.3}

 \setcounter{totalnumber}{20}
 \setcounter{topnumber}{15}
 \setcounter{bottomnumber}{5}

 \makeatletter
 \setlength{\@fptop}{2pt} % float at the top
 \setlength{\@fpsep}{0pt}
 \setlength{\@fpbot}{7pt}
 \makeatother

 \clubpenalty = 100
 \widowpenalty = 100
 \displaywidowpenalty = 1000

 \newcolumntype{I}{!{\vrule width 1.5pt}}
 \newcommand{\amp}{&}
 \newcommand{\gt}{\>}
 \newcommand{\mlt}{<}
 \newcommand{\mgt}{>}
 \newcommand{\mue}{\mu}
 \newcommand{\Mue}{\Mu}
 \newcommand{\nue}{\nu}
 \newcommand{\Nue}{Nu}

 \definecolor{link}{rgb}{0,0,1} 

\hypersetup{%
  colorlinks, linkcolor=link, filecolor=link, urlcolor=link, citecolor=link,
  pdfpagemode=UseOutlines,
  pdfcreator=TrainBraC, pdfauthor={E. Hohmann}, pdfproducer=PDFLaTeX,
  pdftitle=Schulungsprojekt, pdfsubject=Brake calculation
}
\graphicspath{ {./images/} }

\makeatletter % <=======================================================
\AddToShipoutPicture{ \setlength{\@tempdimb}{.5\paperwidth} \setlength{\@tempdimc}{.5\paperheight} \setlength{\unitlength}{1pt} \put(\strip@pt\@tempdimb,\strip@pt\@tempdimc){ \makebox(0,0){\rotatebox{45}{\textcolor[gray]{0.75}{\fontsize{3cm}{3cm}\selectfont{Draft}}}} } }
\makeatother % <========================================================

\pagenumbering{roman}


\begin{document}
\section*{Table of content}\startcontents\printcontents{l}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}
\clearpage
\phantomsection\section*{List of modifications}\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of modifications}
\begin{longtable}{c|c|c|p{7.5cm}} % <===================================
Revision & Date & File processed by & Notes \\ \hline % <===============
02       &\hyperref[frog]{frog}
                & E. Hohmann        &Test of new UNIBRAKE calculation method of WZ + PEC7 brake units, combination according to  force/pressure equation\\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\clearpage

\section{Information of Software Versions}
\subsection{Information of Versions}

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \caption{Version of brake system DLLs} \\ % <===========================
  \hline
  TrainPart&Type&Version&Designation\\ \hline % <=========================
\endfirsthead
  \caption{ContinuationVersion of brake system DLLs} \\ % <===============
  \hline
  TrainPart&Type&Version&Designation\\ \hline % <=========================
\endhead
  \hline
  \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Continued on next page} \\ % <=====================
  \hline
\endfoot
  \hline
  \multicolumn{4}{c}{} \\ % <=============================================
\endlastfoot
M & Electrodynamic brake & 1.0.1 & \phantomsection\label{frog}Frog\\
  & Tread brake unit     & 1.0.0 & PECM\\
  & Tread brake unit     & 1.0.0 & PECMP\\
\hline
N1&Tread brake unit&1.0.0&PECN1\\
&Tread brake unit&1.0.0&PECN1P\\
&Electrodynamic brake&1.0.1&ED N1\\
\hline
T&Disc brake&1.0.0&UPT\\
&Tread brake unit&1.0.0&PECT\\
&Tread brake unit&1.0.0&PECTP\\
\hline
N2&Tread brake unit&1.0.0&PECN2\\
&Tread brake unit&1.0.0&PECN2P\\
&Electrodynamic brake&1.0.1&ED N2\\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

and its result:

[image: resulting longtable]

Now a remark to your used `\hyperref[frog]{frog}`:  if you want to be able to create a link to a special word, for example `frog` in your text, you need to use `hypertarget` to define the target for a link `frog`: `\hypertarget{frog}{text of link frog}`. The link to target `frog` is then writen as `\hyperlink{frog}{text to link to frog}` in the tex code ...

As you can see in the following shorter mwe, based on your changed code, you can use

```
\hyperlink{lb:EDM}{EDM} %\hyperref[lb:EDM]{EDM}
```

and

```
\hypertarget{lb:EDM}{ED M} \\ %\phantomsection{ED M}\label{lb:EDM}\\
```

in your both tables.

With the complete code

```
\documentclass[a4paper, twoside]{article}
\pagenumbering{roman}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{titletoc} 
\usepackage{titlesec} 
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{color} 
\usepackage{tabularx} 

\usepackage{hyperref}

\definecolor{link}{rgb}{0,0,1}
\hypersetup{%
  colorlinks, 
  linkcolor=link, filecolor=link, urlcolor=link, citecolor=link, 
  pdfpagemode=UseOutlines, pdfcreator=TrainBraC, pdfauthor={E. Hohmann}, 
  pdfproducer=PDFLaTeX, pdftitle=Schulungsprojekt, 
  pdfsubject=Brake calculation
}
\pagenumbering{roman}


\begin{document}
\section*{Table of content}\startcontents\printcontents{l}{1}{\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}}
\clearpage
\phantomsection
\section*{List of modifications}
\addcontentsline{toc}{section}{List of modifications}
\begin{longtable}{c|c|c|p{7.5cm}} % <===================================
Revision & Date & File processed by & Notes \\ \hline % <===============
02       & \hyperlink{lb:EDM}{EDM} %\hyperref[lb:EDM]{EDM} <============
                & E. Hohmann        &Test of new UNIBRAKE calculation method of WZ + PEC7 brake units, combination according to  force/pressure equation\\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\clearpage

\section{Information of Software Versions}
\subsection{Information of Versions}

\begin{longtable}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \caption{Version of brake system DLLs} \\ % <===========================
  \hline
  TrainPart&Type&Version&Designation\\ \hline % <=========================
\endfirsthead
  \caption{ContinuationVersion of brake system DLLs} \\ % <===============
  \hline
  TrainPart&Type&Version&Designation\\ \hline % <=========================
\endhead
  \hline
  \multicolumn{4}{|c|}{Continued on next page} \\ % <=====================
  \hline
\endfoot
  \hline
  \multicolumn{4}{c}{} \\ % <=============================================
\endlastfoot
M & Electrodynamic brake & 1.0.1 & \hypertarget{lb:EDM}{ED M} \\ %\phantomsection{ED M}\label{lb:EDM}\\
  & Tread brake unit     & 1.0.0 & PECM\\
  & Tread brake unit     & 1.0.0 & PECMP\\
\hline
N1& Tread brake unit     & 1.0.0 & PECN1\\
  & Tread brake unit     & 1.0.0 & PECN1P\\
  & Electrodynamic brake & 1.0.1 & ED N1\\
\hline
T & Disc brake           & 1.0.0 & UPT\\
  & Tread brake unit     & 1.0.0 & PECT\\
  & Tread brake unit     & 1.0.0 & PECTP\\
\hline
N2& Tread brake unit     &1.0.0  &PECN2\\
  & Tread brake unit     &1.0.0  &PECN2P\\
  & Electrodynamic brake &1.0.1  &ED N2\\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

you get the following starting page with the blue link:

[image: page with link]

After clicking on the link marked with the red circle you get the following page shown:

[image: linked page]

marked with the red arrow is the target. Note that the showed page can be depend on the used pdf viewer, I'm using SumatraPDF.

Comment: Still facing same issue. I am using Adobe reader.

Comment: With given code, I am able to redirect to a correct page, but when I am setting 100% as a zoom and click on the link, it redirects to a page but destined item (EDM in this case) is out of focus. For reference find screenshot number 2.